# Very simple, but yet important question

Tags: etymology, syntactic-analysis

I have seen recently the following in writing:

> This is a very simple, but yet an important observation.

I am almost certain that the [modern] use of *but yet* here is a typo, and the intentions were to use either of the two words (but the author might have hesitated which form to use to the point where s/he simply forgot to remove one of those).

I started searching, and found a few [threads](https://www.reddit.com/r/grammar/comments/4ikxxg/but_yet/), pointing to an interesting [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but+yet&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbut%20yet%3B%2Cc0) chart.

The simple question is whether or not the sentence above is correct (and why?); but more importantly, I think it might worth sharing the story behind the archaic use of this strange expression. That is why I tagged this question accordingly.

---

Related: ['Although' paired with 'yet' in a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124463/although-paired-with-yet-in-a-sentence)

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just bad writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think: ''this is a very simple, yet important observation'' would be correct,
or the same sentence with ''but'' instead of yet.

See also: [Usage of "yet" and comma](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203215/usage-of-yet-and-comma)